# Fetch Set Cookie In Apex

Tags: apex, javascript

I have a javascript snippet which populates the cookie value. Now i need to fetch this value inside a controller.

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays) {
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
}
```

this is the button onclick:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" 
        onclick="setCookie('apex__datecookie', 
                           Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000),100)">
        Close
</button>
```

class:

```
System.Cookie cookie = ApexPages.currentPage().getCookies().get('datecookie');   
if (cookie != null) {
    String field = cookie.getValue();
    Integer date= cookie.getMaxAge();
}
```

I am getting the cookie value as some number inside the log. How can i convert this into date value?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript code `new Date().getTime()` would return time in *ticks* (which are amount of milliseconds between 1 january 1970 and now)

To convert it to DateTime, next code (**DateTime** static method) may to be used in Apex method:

```
String field = cookie.getValue();
Long field_long = Long.valueOf(field);
DateTime result_date = DateTime.newInstance(field_long);
```

Documentation about DateTime class is [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.html)